# Geometry Node Scattering Patterns are not very random

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to scatter objects across a plane using geometry nodes however the random patterns are not very random. You can also see that the ends of the lines all have the same object instanced, as well as the pattern from there.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

if you check "whole collection" it will place all objects on every point (in a "normal" case, you don't want that).

Here the difference:

[image]

[image]

Are you sure that you are showing us the right node tree, which fits to your result? If you have a density of 0  - you would normally see ...nothing. Maybe it would be better if you provide your blend file, so we can help you more precisely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I unticked the whole collection box and everything was fixed. Also, the reason that the density said "0" was because it was actually 0.00001, but it just showed as 0 until you clicked on it.

Comment: Please click the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you. Thank you!!